# playing tone with pyaudio

Tags: python, numpy, audio, pyaudio

im trying to create an audio stream player that will receive audio through TCP, play it and save into file. This is just the player block part. For some reason pyaudio doesnt play the sine wave (sounddevice does, so its fine in the source format at least). Ive tried to play the converted format with sounddevice but without success, so that's probably where the issue lies. Can anyone point me to the right direction? thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import sounddevice as sd
from array import array
import wave

sample_rate = 44100
Fs = 50000
f = 5000
sample = 150000

def play_stream(ob):
    
    "converting object to pyauido required format"
    tone = ob.astype(np.int16)
    bytestream = tone.tobytes()
    
    "playing data with pyaudio"
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                      channels=1,
                      rate=sample_rate,
                      output=True)
    
    if len(bytestream)>0:
        stream.write(bytestream)
    else:
        print("no data!")
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    print("* stream finished")
    p.terminate()

    "testing data in alternate method"
    sd.play(ob, 44100)
    print ("play finished!")

"generating sine wave"
x = np.arange(sample)
ob = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x /Fs)

"playing sine wave"
play_stream(ob)
```

Edit: If i swap the format and data to float 32 it works. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

np.sin' returns a value in the range of -1 to 1.  The 'astype' call is just  casting it to a 16-bit integer which will give possible outputs of -1, 0, and 1. To use the full 16-bit range you need to multiply by 32767 before quantization.

```
scaled = ob * 32767
tone = scaled.totype(np.int16)
```